# Check checkbox if MYSQL column value true

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox, input

I have a todo list app. It has a column called completed which has true or false values. I want the checkbox to be checked if completed is true. I came up with the following:

```
echo "<label>".$row["name"]."</label>
      <input onload='choose(".$row["completed"].")' class='sssss' value='".$row['id']."' type='checkbox'/>";
```

And

```
<script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script>
function choose(a) {
  $(this).attr('checked', a);
}
</script>
```

But it isn't working. Please help

**Edit**

I believe that the js code is only using the first column value for all checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a different way:

```
if ($row['completed'] == 'true'){
    echo "<input class='sssss' value='".$row['id']."' type='checkbox' disabled checked/>";
}else {
    echo "<input class='sssss' value='".$row['id']."' type='checkbox' disabled />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use set the check with PHP:

```
echo "<label>".$row["name"]."</label>
  <input class='sssss' value='".$row['id']."' type='checkbox' ". ($row['completed'] == 'true') ? 'checked' : ''." />";
```

The ternary `$row['completed'] == 'true' ? 'checked' : ''` will echo checked if it's true, and nothing if it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my column has either true or false as the value (false is the default value that can't be checked)

Comment: That's what this does. `empty` checks to see if the variable exists and if it is equal to 0, empty text ('') or false. So !empty is 1) Does it exist (yes) 2) does it contain a positive value (yes). So it will echo 'checked' if the value is true. And I'm editing the answer to use the correct index (oops).

Comment: No I mean the column is VARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
echo "<label>".$row["name"]."</label>
<input ".($row["completed"]) ? 'checked' : ''." class='sssss' value='".$row['id']."' type='checkbox'/>";
```